# Two scrollView should move together in single touch in any one scrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am working on `UIScrollView` and I'm new in programming.
How to scroll two `UIScrollView` simultaneous in one touch in any one scrollView
if I scroll 1st scrollView then 2nd scrollView should also move with 1st scrolView
If anyone have idea, pls suggest me

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the help of delegate method of `UIScrollView`. Here is the demo code for you :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == scroll1)
    {
        scroll2.contentOffset = CGPointMake(content x and y of your scroll1);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beat me to it! +1 for saying what I was going to say. And `[mySecondScrollView setContentOffset:myFirstScrollView.contentOffset];` could simplify the process. This of course assumes that both scroll views have the same size and content size.

Comment: Couldn't you just say `scroll2.contentOffset = scroll1.contentOffset;`?

Comment: @AaronBrager yes I can. But I wasn't sure if both the scroll view is of same size. And I'm sure this delegate will solve the purpose. Just wanted bhanu to play around and understand more. As he is a new programer.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIScrollView *otherView = (scrollView==scroll2)?scroll1:scroll2;

CGPoint offSet = otherView.contentOffset;
offSet.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

[otherView setContentOffset:offSet];
```